# How do I subquery the right results

Tags: mysql, sql, wamp, innodb

I am trying to do a join subquery to return just employee names that earn less than 46000 and I can get it to work by also returning the employee id but not without it.

This is how Im doing it.

```
Select e.eid, e.ename
From employee_table e
Inner Join (
Select salary, eid 
from salary
Where salary > 46000
) as s
On e.eid = s.eid;
```

Comment: I would start with `<` rather than `>`.

Comment: You `select e.eid, e.ename`. If you want the name only then `select e.ename`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the salary isn't stored in the employee table, but in a separate salary table. The salary table contains the employee ID. This makes this a 1:n relation, i.e. one employee can have more than one salary.

I don't know your tables, so I don't know the reason for this. Maybe an employee can have many jobs, or there are part salaries like a base salary and additional salaries, or there is a date range stored with the salary to indicate when it is/was valid. I don't know.

Let's say, we can simply add an employee's salaries to get the total. Then we select the employee names from the employee table where we find a salary less than 46000 in the salary table.

```
select ename
from employee
where eid in
(
  select eid
  from salary
  group by eid
  having sum(salary) < 46000
);
```

Answer (score 2):

This beacuse you are using a dinamic temporary table and if you don't select the eid column your temporary dinamica table don't contain this values and the on clause in join fails

```
  Select e.eid, e.ename
  From employee_table e
  Inner Join (
      Select salary, eid 
      from salary
      Where salary < 46000
  ) as s
  On e.eid = s.eid;
```

you can use an inner join without dinamic temporary table

```
  Select e.eid, e.ename
  From employee_table e
  INNER JOIN salary s On e.eid = s.eid
  where s.salary < 46000
```